# Renaming files in Rails model with multiple Paperclip attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rename

I have a Rails model that has 4 Paperclip attachment types (top_graphic, intro_graphic, bg_audio, and thumbnail), each of which needs to have its file renamed according to different logic upon upload. How can I check which of the 4 attachments is currently being updated in the post-processor in order to do so?

```
before_post_process :file_rename

def file_rename
  # e.g., if top_graphic file is being uploaded, rename file to "top_graphic.jpg"
  # e.g., if intro_graphic file is being uploaded, rename file to "intro_graphic.jpg"
end
```

** Please note that I do know that I could create 4 new models for each of the attachment types and attach them that way. I wish to avoid doing this as it seems like unnecessary filesystem and database clutter.

Thanks.

Comment: Au contraire monsieur, eet ees vous 'oo needs to tell us 'ow. Is it something inside the model's attributes? Some property of the file?

Comment: Not sure what you meant above. In short, the model has 4 cases of has_attached_file and I need to run a different post process task for each one.

Comment: Wasn't aware that paperclip does multiple attachments to the same model... however, has_attached_file allows you to define specific post-processors using :processors. Find it under "Post Processing" in the readme. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip